# Gamma Distribution: what to do after calculating Shape and Rate? How to proceed?

Tags: equation-solving, probability-or-statistics

I got stuck while applying Gamma Distribution. Having `Mean = 5` and `Standard Deviation = 2`, here's how I preceded:

```
shape (a) = (5/2)² = 25/4 = 6.25
rate (b) = 5/2² = 5/4 = 1.25
...
```

After that i don't know how to proceed. Could someone help me by showing me the example with numbers?

Answer (score 2):

Up to [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution), we can write down a system of algebraic equations `5==s/r&&2^2==s/r^2`, where `s` stands for shape and `r` denotes rate, and solve it

```
Solve[5 == s/r && 2^2 == s/r^2, {s, r}]
```

> `{{s -> 25/4, r -> 5/4}}`

We deal with `GammaDistribution[25/4,4/5]` in [Mathematica notation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GammaDistribution.html?q=GammaDistribution).

Comment: As far as I can see, the equation is only demonstrative, because it returns 6.25 and 1.25 as results (already calculated as shape and rate). Does it mean that the gamma distribution ends with the calculation of shape and rate and that nothing else is needed afterwards? Will the final results of the gamma distribution be two: 6.25 and 1.25?

Comment: Sorry. don't understand it. Can you say in other words what you want?

Comment: Not being a mathematician (but just a simple enthusiast), I'm getting confused. What is the final result of this Gamma Distribution?

Answer (score 2):

```
$Version

(* "13.3.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 24, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

dist = GammaDistribution[a, b];

{m, s} = {Mean[dist], StandardDeviation[dist]}

(* {a b, Sqrt[a] b} *)
```

Solving for the parameters for a given mean and standard deviation,

```
param = Solve[{m == 5, s == 2}, {a, b}][[1]]

(* {a -> 25/4, b -> 4/5} *)
```

Verifying the solution,

```
{m, s} /. param

(* {5, 2} *)
```

The mode is

```
mode = Solve[{D[PDF[dist /. param, x], x] == 0, x > 0}, x][[1]]

(* {x -> 21/5} *)
```

Or,

```
{max, arg} = Maximize[PDF[dist /. param, x], x]
```

[image]

```
{max, arg} // N

(* {0.214218, {x -> 4.2}} *)

ticks = StringDelete[
  ToString /@ Range["m" - 3 "s", "m" + 3 "s", "s"], " "]

(* {"m-3s", "m-2s", "m-s", "m", "m+s", "m+2s", "m+3s"} *)

Plot[PDF[dist /. param, x], {x, 0, 10},
 Frame -> True,
 FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, 
    None}, {Automatic, {ToExpression[#] /. param, #} & /@ ticks}},
 GridLines -> {Range[m - 3 s, m + 3 s, s] /. param, None},
 Epilog -> {Dashed,
   InfiniteLine[{{x, 0}, {x, 1}}] /. mode}]
```

[image]

Comment: Not being a mathematician (but just a simple enthusiast), I'm getting confused. What is the final result of this Gamma Distribution? (the value of the final result I mean). Is it a=25/4, b=4/5, or a=6.25 and b=1.25? Or other?

Comment: Ah, I read 5/21. So is the final result 21/5 or 4.2?

Comment: `GammaDistribution[a, b]` is a distribution. It doesn't have a value but its properties have values. When its mean is `5` and standard deviation is `2`, then its mode (peak) occurs at `x == 21/5 == 4.2` and the peak value is approximately `0.214218`

Comment: So the final solution is 0.214218?

Comment: Only if the goal was to find the peak value of the PDF. There are an infinite number of properties that can be evaluated, e.g., Mean, StandardDeviation, r-th Moment, r-th CentralMoment, PDF at some value, CDF at some value, mode, probability that x is less than or greater than some value, …

Comment: Anyway I upvoted your answer. I'll study it carefully tomorrow and get back to you. Thank you